# Write to Excel using C#. ( function that will enter one value into an excel every time its called)

Tags: c#, excel

I need help writing a function that will input one string into a cell in Excel using C#.
This issue I am having is when I try to use a counter to make sure the sheet only created one time I get an error. If I don't have the if statement there, the code will just make numerous sheets and only save the last data point in the cell that equals the value of Excelcounter.

```
      public void WriteSample()
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            if (excelApp != null)
            {
                if (Excelcounter == 0) // data_count keeps track of how many operations i have made to excel
                {
                    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(); // Initalize the excell sheet
                    Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add();
                }
                    Excelcounter++; // increment
                
// in the lines below anything that has to with the variable "excelWorkbook" and "excelWorksheet' will give an error 
                excelWorksheet.Cells[Excelcounter, 1] = str4; // add data to excel (this is where i am getting my error)
                

                excelWorkbook.Close(); // close Excel 
                excelApp.Quit();

                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorksheet);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            }
        }
```

I know that the reason I am getting an error is because the variables are separated from their interface (not sure if interface is the correct term for it). I am very new to C# this is only my 2nd project using this language. Is there a way I can continue using the logic I have in the code above without adding massive amounts of code (this might confuse me even more)? Thank you very much guys!!

Comment: Your variables are out of scope for where you're using them. The procedure you're trying to use them in can't access anything it can't see. It's difficult to tell you exactly what you need to do to fix the issue, because you've not provided a [mre] that demonstrates the problem that includes the location where those variables are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Add a reference to Microsoft.Excel  Object Library (ex: Microsoft.Excel 16.0 Object Library)

- On menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference**
- Select **COM**
- Select **Microsoft.Excel xx.x Object Library** (ex: Microsoft.Excel 16.0 Object Library)

Add the following using statements:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

**Option 1:**

If you want to set a string value referencing the cell by row,column:

```
public void ExcelWriteValue(string filename, int rowNum, int colNum, string dataValue, string worksheetName = "")
{
    //Write cell value using row number and column number

    //*Note: Excel cells, can also be referenced by name, such as "B2"
    //
    //       All indices in Excel (rowNumber, columnNumber, etc...) start with 1 
    //       The format is: <rowNumber>, <columnNumber>
    //       The top left-most column, is: 1,1



    bool specifiedWorksheetFound = false;
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Excel.Application excelApp = null;
    Excel.Worksheet previousActiveSheet = null;
    Excel.Range range = null;
    Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
    
    //keep track of existing worksheet names
    SortedDictionary<string, bool> worksheetDict = new SortedDictionary<string, bool>();

    int worksheetCount = 0;

    try
    {

        //create new instance
        excelApp = new Excel.Application();

        //suppress displaying alerts (such as prompting to overwrite existing file)
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

        //set Excel visability
        excelApp.Visible = false;

        //if writing/updating a large amount of data
        //disable screen updating by setting value to false
        //for better performance.
        //re-enable when done writing/updating data, if desired
        //excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;


        if (excelApp != null)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("'" + filename + "' exists. Existing file will be modified.");

                //open existing Excel file
                workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);

                //get number of existing worksheets
                worksheetCount = workbook.Sheets.Count;

                if (worksheetCount >= 1)
                {
                    foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in workbook.Sheets)
                    {
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("worksheet name: '" + ws.Name + "'");

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheetName) && ws.Name == worksheetName)
                        {
                            //set value to desired/specified worksheet
                            worksheet = ws;

                            //set value
                            specifiedWorksheetFound = true;
                        }

                        if (!worksheetDict.ContainsKey(ws.Name))
                        {
                            //add worksheet name to dictionary
                            //the bool value isn't used, so it's value isn't important
                            //it exists because a Dictionary requires both a key and a value
                            worksheetDict.Add(ws.Name, true);
                        }
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheetName) && !specifiedWorksheetFound)
                    {
                        //specified worksheet not found

                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: Worksheet '" + worksheetName + "' not found in filename '" + filename + "'.", "Error - Worksheet Not Found", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheetName) && specifiedWorksheetFound)
                    {
                        //set value 
                        previousActiveSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                        //specified worksheet found
                        //activate desired worksheet
                        worksheet.Activate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //set value 
                        previousActiveSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                        //no worksheet name specified
                        //default to 1st worksheet
                        worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

                        //active worksheet
                        worksheet.Activate();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //no worksheets exist
                    //add a worksheet and set the value to the new worksheet
                    worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Add();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("'" + filename + "' doesn't exit. Creating new workbook.");

                //create new workbook
                workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

                //get number of existing worksheets
                worksheetCount = workbook.Sheets.Count;

                //add a worksheet and set the value to the new worksheet
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Add();

            }


            //set cell location that data needs to be written to
            //range = worksheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum];

            //set value of cell
            //range.Value = dataValue;

            //set value of cell
            worksheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum] = dataValue;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Info: Value for cell " + rowNum + "," + colNum + " in worksheet '" + worksheet.Name + "' set.");

            if (previousActiveSheet != null)
            {
                //restore active sheet to one that was previously the active sheet
                //so that when the user opens the workbook, it will open to the last sheet he/she opened
                worksheet = previousActiveSheet;
                worksheet.Activate();
            }

            //save Workbook - if file exists, overwrite it
            workbook.SaveAs(filename, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status: Complete. " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errMsg = "Error: ExcelWriteValue - " + ex.Message;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errMsg);

        if (ex.Message.StartsWith("Cannot access read-only document"))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "Please close the workbook, before trying again.", "Error - Unable To Write To Workbook", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (workbook != null)
        {
            //set value
            range = null;
            previousActiveSheet = null;
            worksheet = null;

            //close workbook
            workbook.Close();

            //release all resources
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
        }

        if (excelApp != null)
        {
            //close Excel
            excelApp.Quit();

            //release all resources
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:** The SortedDictionary isn't used. I added it in case you need to keep track of existing worksheet names.

**Option 2:**

If you want to set a string value referencing the cell by name (ex: "B2"):

```
public void ExcelWriteValue(string filename, string cellName, string dataValue, string worksheetName = "")
{
    //Write cell value using the Excel cell name (ex: B2)

    //*Note: Excel cells, can also be referenced by row,column such as "1,2"
    //
    //       All indices in Excel (rowNumber, columnNumber, etc...) start with 1 
    //       The format is: <rowNumber>, <columnNumber>
    //       The top left-most column, is: 1,1



    bool specifiedWorksheetFound = false;
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Excel.Application excelApp = null;
    Excel.Worksheet previousActiveSheet = null;
    Excel.Range range = null;
    Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;

    //keep track of existing worksheet names
    SortedDictionary<string, bool> worksheetDict = new SortedDictionary<string, bool>();

    int worksheetCount = 0;

    try
    {

        //create new instance
        excelApp = new Excel.Application();

        //suppress displaying alerts (such as prompting to overwrite existing file)
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

        //set Excel visability
        excelApp.Visible = false;


        //if writing/updating a large amount of data
        //disable screen updating by setting value to false
        //for better performance.
        //re-enable when done writing/updating data, if desired
        //excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;


        if (excelApp != null)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("'" + filename + "' exists. Existing file will be modified.");

                //open existing Excel file
                workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);

                //get number of existing worksheets
                worksheetCount = workbook.Sheets.Count;

                if (worksheetCount >= 1)
                {
                    foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in workbook.Sheets)
                    {
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("worksheet name: '" + ws.Name + "'");

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheetName) && ws.Name == worksheetName)
                        {
                            //set value to desired/specified worksheet
                            worksheet = ws;

                            //set value
                            specifiedWorksheetFound = true;
                        }

                        if (!worksheetDict.ContainsKey(ws.Name))
                        {
                            //add worksheet name to dictionary
                            //the bool value isn't used, so it's value isn't important
                            //it exists because a Dictionary requires both a key and a value
                            worksheetDict.Add(ws.Name, true);
                        }
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheetName) && !specifiedWorksheetFound)
                    {
                        //specified worksheet not found

                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Worksheet '" + worksheetName + "' not found in filename '" + filename + "'.", "Error - Worksheet Not Found", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheetName) && specifiedWorksheetFound)
                    {
                        //set value 
                        previousActiveSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                        //specified worksheet found
                        //activate desired worksheet
                        worksheet.Activate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //set value 
                        previousActiveSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

                        //no worksheet name specified
                        //default to 1st worksheet
                        worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

                        //active worksheet
                        worksheet.Activate();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //no worksheets exist
                    //add a worksheet and set the value to the new worksheet
                    worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Add();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("'" + filename + "' doesn't exit. Creating new workbook.");

                //create new workbook
                workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

                //get number of existing worksheets
                worksheetCount = workbook.Sheets.Count;

                //add a worksheet and set the value to the new worksheet
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Add();

            }

            

            //set cell location that data needs to be written to
            //range = worksheet.Range[cellName];

            //set value of cell
            //range.Value = dataValue;

            //set value of cell
            worksheet.Range[cellName].Value = dataValue;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Info: Value for cell " + cellName + " in worksheet '" + worksheet.Name + "' set.");

            if (previousActiveSheet != null)
            {
                //restore active sheet to one that was previously the active sheet
                //so that when the user opens the workbook, it will open to the last sheet he/she opened
                worksheet = previousActiveSheet;
                worksheet.Activate();
            }

            //save Workbook - if file exists, overwrite it
            workbook.SaveAs(filename, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status: Complete. " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errMsg = "Error: ExcelWriteValue - " + ex.Message;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errMsg);

        if (ex.Message.StartsWith("Cannot access read-only document"))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "Please close the workbook, before trying again.", "Error - Unable To Write To Workbook", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (workbook != null)
        {
            //set value
            range = null;
            previousActiveSheet = null;
            worksheet = null;

            //close workbook
            workbook.Close();

            //release all resources
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
        }

        if (excelApp != null)
        {
            //close Excel
            excelApp.Quit();

            //release all resources
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:** The SortedDictionary isn't used. I added it in case you need to keep track of existing worksheet names.

If this was helpful, please mark it as the answer.