# saving data from c# to Excel crashes

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, save

I work on a project where I'd like to save some data in an Excel sheet,

Here is my code:

```cs
private void myButton11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelworkbook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelsheet;

    excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excel.Visible = false;
    excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

    excelworkbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

    excelsheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelworkbook.ActiveSheet;
    excelsheet.Name = "dataToExcel";
    // fill in data
    excelsheet.Cells[1, 1] = "test";
    excelsheet.Cells[3, 3] = "test2";

    // save excel
    excelworkbook.SaveAs(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "//dataToExcel.xls",
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
        true, true, 1, 10, false);
}
```

The problem is when executing it crashes and shows me this error message:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x800A03EC
  Message=Coudn't access file. Please try thoses options :

• Make sure the file exist. 
• Make sure the file is not in read only.
• Make sure file path isn't containing thoses characteres:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *
• Make sure the file path and names do not take more than 218 caracteres.

C:\Users\corentin.boudaud\source\repos\FabLoop_project_V0.0.0\FabLoop_project_V0.0.0\Program.cs :ligne 20
```

The crash occurs on "SaveAs", the file I'm writing to is in my documents (public, write available)

Any idea where the problem might come from?

Thanks

Comment: Recommend using https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus or https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML

Comment: Does it really say "thoses options" and "thoses characteres" or did you translate the error message yourself?

Comment: Message=We were unable to access the file. Try one of the following options:

- Make sure the specified folder exists. 
- Make sure the folder containing the file is not in Read Only mode.
- Make sure the file name and folder path do not contain any of the following characters: < > ?  [ ] : | or *
- Make sure the file name and folder path are no longer than 218 characters.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045576/write-to-excel-using-c-function-that-will-enter-one-value-into-an-excel-ever/65053425#65053425

Comment: The code works for me, please check your path and make sure the file path and names do not take more than 218 characters. Besides, you can consider saving it to other path and test again.

Comment: The workbook needs to be closed. Also add `excel.Quit()` to quit Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,

when using excelworkbook.SaveAs(), the path need to be using '\' to set the path and not '/'

I can then save the file as I want, .csv .xls or .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

You can save it easy as a .csv file. CSV is also a tabel and if you open it it will open in excel.

You can do this with System.IO

**Thats a csv file in excel:**

[image]

**and thats a csv file in notepad++**

[image]

Comment: I was looking for something a human can read... csv might be a problem for this

Comment: no when you open an csv in exel it's a normal table

Comment: I added pictures